# How to create a bootstrap circled button with the text centered

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a button for numbers a round button. I am able to do it but the text(number is not centered). Ideally if i have 1 to 15 circular 15 buttons from 1 to 15

Code below

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link
  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  id="bootstrap-css"
>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg">100</button>
```

The above code is used from this [link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dKB)

Comment: This question is not about how to center text in general, but with bootstrap. As the first answer shows you can accomplish this by simply adding css classes, voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include the CSS for `.btn-circle` to have the rounded corners. I copied the CSS from the link you provided and removed all padding so the text is centered. This will result in:

```css
.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0; // changed
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.btn-circle.btn-lg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0; // changed
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0; // changed
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg">100</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

A very simple class will solve your problem-

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info p-5 rounded-circle btn-lg">100</button>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    body {
  padding: 1em;
}
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info p-5 rounded-circle btn-lg">100</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

These changes will produce circular buttons with centered text:

1. include the `.btn-circle` css rules from the link you provided,
2. wrap the button text in a `span` and give the `span` negative margins.

```css
body {
  padding: 1em;
}

.btn-circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-lg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
}


/* use negative margins to accommodate wider button text */

.btn-circle span {
  margin: 0 -2rem;
}
```

```html
<link
  href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  id="bootstrap-css"
>

<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg"
><span>100</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Bootstrap 4**, using SCSS variables, I implemented circular buttons that are in sync with the size of the default buttons.

I've used the following code:

**SCSS**

```scss
$btn-height-border: $btn-border-width * 2;

$btn-circular-height: add(
  $btn-line-height * 1em,
  add($btn-padding-y * 2, $btn-height-border, false)
);
$btn-circular-height-sm: add(
  $btn-line-height-sm * 1em,
  add($btn-padding-y-sm * 2, $btn-height-border, false)
);
$btn-circular-height-lg: add(
  $btn-line-height-lg * 1em,
  add($btn-padding-y-lg * 2, $btn-height-border, false)
);

.btn-circular {
  width: $btn-circular-height;
  height: $btn-circular-height;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 1;
  
  &.btn-sm {
    width: $btn-circular-height-sm;
    height: $btn-circular-height-sm;
  }

  &.btn-lg {
    width: $btn-circular-height-lg;
    height: $btn-circular-height-lg;  
  }

}
```

**Codepen**:
https://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/vYvBJKB

Answer (score 0):

css

```
<style>
    .user-icon-circle {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #007bff; 
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      color: #fff;
    }
    </style>
```

html

```
            <div class="user-icon-circle">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
            </div>
```